# Error in subtracting datetime

Tags: c#, runtime-error, file-transfer

I have C# application in which transferring file from one server to another.
Then, I have this piece of code that is checking when the files were arrived:

```
foreach (string folder in folders)
{ 
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    TimeSpan t = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dir.LastWriteTime);

    string message = String.Format("File arrived for {0} mins", 
                                    (int)t.Duration().TotalMinutes);
}
```

I tested in local, everything went fine. But in actual server, it returns same minutes for every files (217 million mins) - which is obviously wrong value.

What is happening?

Comment: Probably your directory doesn't exist. Check `dir.Exists` first.

Comment: By the way, I strongly suggest using `DateTime.UtcNow` and `DirectoryInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc` instead of using local timezones to avoid problems with daylight savings.

Comment: @DaveCluderay my directory exists. If I print "Console.WriteLine(folder +" : "+ message);" I will get my folder printed there (D:\temp\file_20140203\). I also did check Directory.Exist(parentfolder) for the parent folder, and for getting folders, I use "string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(parentfolder);"

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry I meant folders.

Answer (score 3):

Reason why you are getting wrong value is because file/folder does not exists.

MSDN states following:

> If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist,
>   this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.)
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

`03rd Feb 2014 - 217 000 000 mins = ~ 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D.`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The folders did exists. But looking at the number, the problem might be around there. Any other possibility that could happen? I am really confuse because it is working fine in local.

Comment: Make sure that correct access rights are set to the folder. If you execute your code under different user account then you should add appropriate  NTFS access rights to that user.

Comment: Hi, I did set the correct access right. I tested in local, if I don't have access right, it will throw exception instead (UnauthorizedAccessException). Really confused.

Comment: There is one more remark in MSDN: `This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system.` You should try call `Refresh` method before querying value. Method info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what is in `folders`, but I suspect those are relative folder names. Try to prepend the actual path:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(parentPath, folder);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
```

Comment: Basically I am listing all folders: "string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(parentPath)"